# React Native Concentric circles

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm building an app with React Native, and I was wondering how I'd go about coding 3 concentric circles like so:

[image]

They would need to be each be touchable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many ways of achieving this. Even though this question isn't the most appropriate to be on StackOverflow, I did some code here to help you.

```
import React from 'react'
import {
    StyleSheet,
    TouchableOpacity,
    View
} from 'react-native'

export default class AboutScreen extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <View style={styles.circlesContainer}>
                    <TouchableOpacity style={styles.circle_1} />
                    <TouchableOpacity style={styles.circle_2} />
                    <TouchableOpacity style={styles.circle_3} />
                </View>
            </View>
        )
    }
}
// Base radius.
const BASE_SIZE = 300

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: { 
        flex:1,
        alignItems:'center',
        justifyContent: 'center',
        backgroundColor: '#E56A00'
    },
    circlesContainer:{
        width: BASE_SIZE,
        height: BASE_SIZE,
        alignItems: 'center',
    },
    circle_1:{
        top:0,
        position: 'absolute',
        width:BASE_SIZE,
        height:BASE_SIZE,
        borderRadius: BASE_SIZE/2,
        backgroundColor: '#FF8100'
    },
    circle_2:{
        top:BASE_SIZE*0.1, // The amount remaining
        left:BASE_SIZE*0.1,
        position: 'absolute',
        width:BASE_SIZE*0.8, // 80% of the base size
        height:BASE_SIZE*0.8,
        borderRadius: BASE_SIZE/2,
        backgroundColor: '#FF9D2E'
    },
    circle_3:{
        top:BASE_SIZE*0.2,
        left:BASE_SIZE*0.2,
        position: 'absolute',
        width:BASE_SIZE*0.6,
        height:BASE_SIZE*0.6, // 60% of the base size
        borderRadius: BASE_SIZE*0.6/2,
        backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF'
    },
})
```

The result on my code looked like this:

[image]

Be aware that there are a lot of ways to optimise this code, but at least it might be a good start to you.

Good luck!

Answer (score -1):

You can use a View with a borderRadius, surrounded by another View, also with a borderRadius.

```
<View style={styles.borderExternal}>
    <View style={styles.myCircle} />
</View>
```